# Add prices to total with checkbox select Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, checkbox, django-templates

I am building a feature to add different services to the checkout in my Django template, but I don't know how to add the total price when selecting checkboxes.

I put a change event on each checkbox and to this and when I check one it is supposed to add the service and its price in the card.

The card :

```
 <div class="col-4">
      <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
        <span class="text-muted">Votre commande</span>
      </h4>
      <ul class="list-group mb-3" id="panier">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
          <div>
            <h6 class="my-0">{{annonce.titre_logement}}</h6>
            <small class="text-muted">{{annonce.categorie_logement}}</small>
          </div>
          <span class="text-muted">{{annonce.loyer_tc}} €</span>
        </li>

      </ul>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span>Total (€)</span>
            <strong><span id="total"></span> €</strong>
        </li>
    </div>
```

The checkboxes and the script :

```
{% for categorie in categorie_service %}
                          {% for service in services %}
                              {% if service.categorie.value == categorie_service.nom %}
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="service" value="{{ service.nom }}" id="service{{ service.id }}">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="service{{ service.id }}">
                                          {{ service.nom }}
                                      </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <script>
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                              $('#service{{ service.id }}').change(function() {
                                            if(this.checked) {
                                                var returnVal = "<li class='list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed'>\
                                      <div>\
                                        <h6 class='my-0'>{{service.nom}}</h6>\
                                      </div>\
                                      <span class='text-muted'>{{service.price}}€</span>\
                                    </li>"
                                        $('#panier').append(returnVal);
                                        var total
                                        total = {{annonce.loyer_tc}}
                                        total = total + parseInt({{service.price}} || 0,10);
                                        totalDiv = document.getElementById("total");
                                        totalDiv.innerHTML = total;
                                           }
                                        });
                                    });
                                    </script>
                              {% endif %}
                          {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
```

and here is my view if needed :

```
def detail_annonce(request, pk):
myObject = Annonce.objects.get(id=pk)
image = ImageLogement.objects.all()
categorie_service = myObject.categorie_service.all()
services = Services.objects.all()
context = {'annonce': myObject, 'myImages': image, 'categorie_service': categorie_service, 'services':services}
return render(request, 'annonce/search/annonce_result.html', context)
```

Comment: Did you resolve this ?